# OpenCV: stitching with OpenCV-4.5.5 ? (built-from-source)

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

Building from source latest OpenCV (4.5.5)

```
~/Programs/opencv$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/opencv/opencv (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/opencv/opencv (push)

~/Programs/opencv$ git status
HEAD detached at 4.5.5
```

Using cmake

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Programs/opencv_contrib/modules -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=~/Programs/opencv/local -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON -DOPENCV_DNN_OPENCL=ON -DBUILD_LIST=core,calib3d,viz,videoio,highgui,python3,stitching ..

make all install
```

Then I update the environment

```
export PATH=~/Programs/opencv/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Programs/opencv/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=~/Programs/opencv/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

But sample provided by OpenCV does not work?!...

```
$ python3 ~/Programs/opencv/samples/python/stitching.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Programs/opencv/samples/python/stitching.py", line 20, in <module>
    modes = (cv.Stitcher_PANORAMA, cv.Stitcher_SCANS)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'Stitcher_PANORAMA'
```

Stitching does not work but all other stuffs (imshow, imread/imwrite, video capture, calibration, ...) does work: What did I miss?

Comment: did you try to install pip version after? `pip3 install opencv-python`, `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` ?

Comment: I have very limited space left (hard drive - embedded device). Didn't install from source as there is no GPU support using `apt-get` install. Need to build from source.

Answer (score 0):

One need to export **both**

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/Programs/opencv/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=~/Programs/opencv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```